# Orthographic projection matrix of view

Tags: python, scripting

The region_3d.view_matrix of an area returns the perpective projection matrix. How to get the orthographic projection matrix for the same view?

Comment: The api docs say the [`perspective_matrix`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.perspective_matrix) is `window_matrix * view_matrix`. The `window_matrix` and `perspective_matrix` change when switching between persp and ortho. `view_matrix` only changes when you pan/rot in the viewport.

Comment: @sambler I was trying to transform the coordinates into view_matrix to get the projection of a point on plane (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150645/projection-of-point-on-plane). That problem is solved. But thank you for this piece of information.